# APK upload: upgrade a previous high versionCode

Tags: apk, google-play-console

I distributed an apk using "yyMMddhhmm" as versionCode. Now I realized that maximum version code is 2100000000 and so I can't upload any upgrade: I have a millenium bug on 2021!

How can I get around?

If I remove previous version, users will receive the new one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android only updates to higher versionCodes, so you can only go higher and never lower. Play Console enforces this but this is a restriction of Android in the first place.

The only option you have is contact the Play Developer support and ask them if they can allow you to publish versions that go all the way to 2,147,483,647 which is theoretically the highest versionCode you can have today.

Obviously, you'll have to adjust your allocation of versionCodes and be more frugal onwards in how you consume them.